# Is there any good tutorial site to develop Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I would like to learn Drupal 7, is there  any good sites to introduce Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

[Seriously...](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=drupal%207%20tutorials&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)